# ipyleaflet with on_hover event, Marker.on_mouseover

Tags: python, leaflet, jupyter, marker, ipywidgets

I just learned ipyleaflet from the scipy 2020 tutorials. In the tutorial example, I have seen the possibilities of having the hover event on ipyleaflet through the GeoJSON. Could anyone tell me how to have a hover event on Marker?

Below is my test try.

```
m = Map(
    basemap=basemaps.CartoDB.DarkMatter,
    center = center,
    zoom = zoom,
    interpolation='nearest'
)

icon1 = AwesomeIcon(
    name = 'paper-plane-o',
    marker_color='red',
    icono_color='black',
    icon_size=(2,2),
    spin=False
)

marker = Marker(icon=icon1,
    name = glider_mission.split('/')[-1],
    location = ([27.19,-82.79]),
    draggable=False,
    opacity=0.5,
    rise_on_hover=True,
)

html = HTML()
def update_html(marker,**kwargs):
    html.value = '''
        <b>Glider Mission:</b><br>
        {}
    '''.format(marker.name)
marker.on_mouseover(update_html(marker))
m.add_layer(marker)
m
```

Jupyter Lab gave me the error, like

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: You need to pass a callable to `on_mouseover`, you are currently calling the function and passing the result: Try


`marker.on_mouseover(update_html)`

Comment: I agreed with you. But what args and kwargs I should provide in the update_html, and how can I have a popup window when hovering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `marker.on_mouseover` method takes a callback function as argument. Here you are calling `update_html(marker)` which returns `None`, which means you are calling `marker.on_mouseover(None)`, hence the error message.

What you want to do is this:

```py
def get_callback(marker, html):
    def callback(*args, **kwargs):
        html.value = '''
            <b>Glider Mission:</b><br>
            {}
        '''.format(marker.name)

    return callback

marker.on_mouseover(get_callback(marker, html))
```

The `get_callback` returns a callback function (a callable), so the `on_mouseover` method won't complain anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Could you also let me know how to get the marker.popup function working in the marker.on_mouseover? Thanks

Comment: marker.popup is not a function, it's a property which should be another widget (the widget that should be displayed when clicking on the marker). There is no way currently to show a popup on hover on a marker. If that is something you would like to see in ipyleaflet, could you open an issue on the Github repo asking for this feature?

Comment: It seems to be a bug with this functionality (marker tooltip) and will be fixed soon.
https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/676